# Relative error of power estimation

Tags: power, signal, frequency, matlab, dsp

I'm reading my teacher code for FFT windowing in Matlab and there is one thing I don't understand. When you run the code at the end it says:

```
Relative error of power estimation [PSP-2S]: 299.8%
Relative error of power estimation [PSP-1S]: 699.6%
Relative error of power estimation [PSP-2S]: 122.1%
Relative error of power estimation [PSP-1S]: 344.1%
```

What does this mean in terms of the signal? Is it something to do with showing that applying the window fucntion has reduced the energy lost into the sidelobes?

```matlab
    %%% Part-1
% Reading the wav file 

[y,Fs]=audioread('signal.wav');

% figure,plot(y),title('Time Domain signal');

t = 0:1/Fs:(length(y)-1)/Fs;

figure(1);

% time based plot

plot(t,y)

title('Time Domain signal');

xlabel('Time (seconds)');

ylabel('Amplitude')

xlim([0 t(end)]);

grid on 
 
%%% Fs 48k Hz

Ts = 1/Fs; % [s]

Duration = 1; % [s]

Ns = floor(Duration/Ts); % [-]

time = ([0:(Ns-1)]')*Ts;

v_signal = y;

% signal energy and power spectral density

energy_viatime = Ts * sum(abs(v_signal).^2);

power_viatime = energy_viatime/((Ns-1)*Ts);

 
% Windowing specifications

% The window used by pspectrum is a Kaiser window with BETA parameter = 40*(1-Leakage)

% where Leakage value is [0;1] (1 = rectwin)

beta = 0; leak = 1-beta/40; % here, i chose a rectwin, i.e. leak = 1

% pspectrum function call

[v_PSP_2S, v_fPSP_2S] = 

pspectrum(v_signal,time,'Leakage',leak,'TwoSided',true,'Reassign',false,'power');

[v_PSP_1S, v_fPSP_1S] = pspectrum(v_signal,time,'Leakage',leak,'TwoSided',false,'Reassign',false,'power');

fprintf('Relative error of power estimation [PSP-2S]: %2.1f%%\n',abs(sum(v_PSP_2S) -
 
power_viatime) / power_viatime * 100);

fprintf('Relative error of power estimation [PSP-1S]: %2.1f%%\n',abs(sum(v_PSP_1S) - 

power_viatime) / power_viatime * 100);

fprintf('\n');

 
%  Bandwidth Scale factor  

dF_window_enbw_2S = enbw(kaiser(size(v_PSP_2S,1),beta),Fs);

sum(v_PSP_2S)*dF_window_enbw_2S; 
 
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Windowing reduces the amplitude of the discontinuities

% at the boundaries of each finite sequence acquired by the digitizer.

x=y;
N = 4*2^nextpow2(length(x));

f1 = 0:Fs/N:Fs/2;

%%%% fast fourier transform  %%%%%

X = fft(x,N)/length(x); 

X1 = abs(X(1:N/2+1));

X1(2:N/2+1) = 2*X1(2:N/2+1);
 
Xphase = unwrap(angle(X(1:N/2+1))); 

 
figure(2);

subplot(2, 2, 1:2)

    plot(t, x); 

    xlabel('t[s]'); ylabel('x(t)');

    title('Signal x(t)'); grid on;

subplot(2, 2, 3)

    plot(f1, X1);

    xlabel('f[Hz]'); ylabel('|X(jf)|');

    title('Amplitude'); grid on;

subplot(2,2,4)

    plot(f1, Xphase);

    xlabel('f[Hz]'); ylabel('arg{X(jf)}');

    title('Phase'); grid on

 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Window specifications %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 
Fpass1 = 4200;             % First Passband Frequency

Fstop1 = 4320;             % First Stopband Frequency

Fstop2 = 4890;             % Second Stopband Frequency

Fpass2 = 4950;             % Second Passband Frequency

Dpass1 = 0.028774368332;   % First Passband Ripple

Dstop  = 0.001;           % Stopband Attenuation

Dpass2 = 0.057501127785;  % Second Passband Ripple
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Kaiser Window %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

[N,Wn,BETA,TYPE] = kaiserord([Fpass1 Fstop1 Fstop2 Fpass2]/(Fs/2), [1 ...

                             0 1], [Dpass1 Dstop Dpass2]);
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Filter specifications %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

b  = fir1(N, Wn, TYPE, 'scale');

 
figure(3);

freqz(b,1,1024,Fs);

y1 = filtfilt(b,1,x);

title('Windowing Filter')
 
N = 4*2^nextpow2(length(y1));

f2 = 0:Fs/N:Fs/2;

Y = fft(y1,N)/length(y1);
 
Y1 = abs(Y(1:N/2+1));

Y1(2:N/2+1) = 2*Y1(2:N/2+1);
 
Yphase = unwrap(angle(Y(1:N/2+1))); 

 
figure(4);

subplot(2, 2, 1:2)

    plot(t, y1); 

    xlabel('t[s]'); ylabel('y(t)');

    title('Signal y(t)'); grid on;

subplot(2, 2, 3)

    plot(f2, Y1);

    xlabel('f[Hz]'); ylabel('|X(jf)|');

    title('Amplitude'); grid on;

subplot(2,2,4)

    plot(f2, Yphase);

    xlabel('f[Hz]'); ylabel('arg{Y(jf)}');

    title('Phase'); grid on
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Recalculating PSP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

beta = 0; 

leak = 1-beta/40;

% pspectrum call again

[v_PSP_2S1, v_fPSP_2S1] =
 
pspectrum(y1,time,'Leakage',leak,'TwoSided',true,'Reassign',false,'power');
[v_PSP_1S1, v_fPSP_1S1] = 


pspectrum(y1,time,'Leakage',leak,'TwoSided',false,'Reassign',false,'power');

fprintf('Relative error of power estimation [PSP-2S]: %2.1f%%\n',abs(sum(v_PSP_2S1) - 

power_viatime) / power_viatime * 100);

    

fprintf('Relative error of power estimation [PSP-1S]: %2.1f%%\n',abs(sum(v_PSP_1S1) - 

power_viatime) / power_viatime * 100);

fprintf('\n');
```

Comment: How does this relate to electrical engineering, and why don't you ask your teacher about the code?